# Successful build but had lots of IntelliSense errors In Typescript (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript, compiler-errors, intellisense

The project I downloaded is from my team, and the project is working perfectly in their machine. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and clone the solution using VS team explore. I though this is about the package versioning problem. So I tried to restore the Packages. After I restore all the missing Nuget Package using "Update-Package -reinstall" command, there are 100+ intellisense errors popup.

Here is the Screenshot of the errors:
[image]

[image]

The TypeScrpit version they used to develop for this project was 2.2. Any help here would be appreciate.

Comment: Hi Daniel, please check your installed TypeScript version like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948348/where-can-i-find-the-typescript-version-installed-in-visual-studio and make sure the Typescript is 2.2 or later. Meanwhile, right click the solution name under Solution Explorer and choose ‘Clean solution’ then build it. Or Close VS 2017, go to the solution store folder, delete the hidden .vs folder, reopen this solution again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I checked the version currently is 2.2.2 and cleaned the solution and rebuild it. Also, I deleted the .vs and reopen VS again, but it doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: It is the build error or intellisense error? You can change the filter to Build Only or Intellisense Only in the Error List window to check it.

Comment: It’s the intellisense error. I’m trying to uninstall the typescript and augularjs from my computer and restore it.

Comment: If you create a new project with the same project type, does this issue persist or not? Please backup this current and create a new blank solution, move the projects one by one into this solution to test.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved this problem by adding the individual component in the Visual Studio Installer . I simply select the TypeScript 2.2 and everything just work out.

Comment: So glad to hear that your issue is solved, please add a reply with your solution and mark it, then will help other community members to easier search this useful information, thanks in advance.