# Visual Studio 2022 - Using TypeScript 3.6 for IntelliSense (newest installed is TypeScript 4.3)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Using `Visual Studio 2022 17.1.3` I get a lot of TypeScript errors and the following warning:

> Using TypeScript 3.6 for IntelliSense (newest installed is TypeScript
> 4.3).

[image]

Running `npm run build` works fine and `package.json` has a `devDependencies` for `"typescript": "^4.5.2"`

The exact same project works on another computer so the setting is probably specific to Visual Studio.

`tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    {
      "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin"
    }
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

`.csproj` TypeScript values:

[image]

Setting not seen in GUI:

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

From this thread:

[Where can I find the TypeScript version installed in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948348/where-can-i-find-the-typescript-version-installed-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with another error I saw:

> Please install the 'Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild' NuGet package to
> enable TypeScript compilation in your project. You can use the NuGet
> Package Manager to do so. Project.Web

After installing the NuGet below everything started working:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/4.6.4

At first I saw:

```
Using TypeScript 4.3 for IntelliSense.
Using TypeScript 4.6 for IntelliSense.
```

But after restarting Visual Studio everything looked good:

```
Using TypeScript 4.6 for IntelliSense.
```